# Как создать файл и переместить его в новую директорию?

Tags: golang

Я создаю пустой файл при помощи `os.Create()`. И я хочу переместить его в новую директорию. Как это можно сделать ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В пределах одного диска можно просто менять название файла:

```go
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    srcPath := "/старый/путь/test.txt"
    dstPath := "/новый/путь/test.txt"
    err := os.Rename(srcPath, dstPath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Готовой универсальной функции нет, но её можно создать так:

```go
import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func MoveFile(srcPath, dstPath string) error {
    inputFile, err := os.Open(srcPath)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Couldn't open source file: %s", err)
    }
    // Создаём нужный файл
    outputFile, err := os.Create(dstPath)
    if err != nil {
        inputFile.Close()
        return fmt.Errorf("Couldn't open dest file: %s", err)
    }
    defer outputFile.Close()
    // Копируем содержимое
    _, err = io.Copy(outputFile, inputFile)
    inputFile.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Writing to output file failed: %s", err)
    }
    // Удаляем исходный файл, если не было ошибок
    err = os.Remove(srcPath)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Failed removing original file: %s", err)
    }
    return nil
}
```

<sub>С ипользованием [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50741908/5308802).</sub>